# How can I add a span after the text in an anchor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to add class=caret to a bootstrap template in a CMS to all anchors with class="has-submenu" as shown in

```
< a href="#" class="has-submenu" 
             id="sm-15840459350560935-1" 
             aria-haspopup="true" 
             aria-controls="sm-15840459350560935-2" 
             aria-expanded="false">Dropdown < span class="caret">< /span>< /a>
```

I tried several solutions like

```
$( "a.has-submenu" ).append(document.createTextNode("."))
                    .html( "<span class='caret'></span>" );
```

Which did not function. `< b> class="caret" < /b>` might also be sufficient, and the code can be in javascript or php.

Comment: Your question seems overly complicated. You're just appending a span to an anchor, right. What's all this about templates and text nodes?

Comment: Are you trying to add a class or an element?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` on your jQuery-Selector and then append your `span`:

```js
$('a.has-submenu').each(function() {
  $(this).append('<span class="caret"></span>')
});
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="has-submenu" id="a1">Text</a>
<a href="#" class="has-submenu" id="a2">Text</a>
<a href="#" class="has-submenu" id="a3">Text</a>
```

Comment: Ruben Danielyan already answered your question. Will leave mine for the snippet.

Comment: This makes a <span>around Dropdown instead of  .... >Dropdown < span class="caret">< /span>< /a>  --- which is my problem...

Comment: In php something like : if( in_array('docs',$attributes['class']) ){ $format = '<a {$attr} class="has-submenu" href="{$href_text}" title="{$title}">{$label}<b class="caret"></b></a>';

Comment: Have a look at my snippet. I just checked again, it provides the following structure:
`<a href="#" class="has-submenu" id="a1">Text<span class="caret"></span></a>`. 
Same nesting you provided as PHP. An `a` with text plus adjacent `span` inside.
Here a CodePen to play with: https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/ExjEELJ

Comment: I guess you are using Bootstrap 3.x.x? The *span.caret* is used for dropdowns in that version. I set the linked version to 3.3.7 to reflect the use of the framework.